# Array of String

Tags: java

This is kind of a continuation of a previous post.
I was wondering how can I create a string array for the string "name"?
Basically I want to user to have the ability to input multiple names in the program (the program keeps on looping until they exit - asks for name of the person then seat # and then the user can print the seating chart or exit). The main section of the code I need to edit is below...

```
    //changes an empty seat to a student's name at any location
    public void emptySeat()
    {
        System.out.println("Who will be taking this seat?");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Which seat would you like (1-24)\n");
        int seat = scan.nextInt();
        if (seat > 0 && seat <= 24) {
            if (seating[seat - 1]) {
                System.out.print("That seat is taken.\n");
            } else {
                seating[seat - 1] = true;
                System.out.print("Seat number " + seat + " was assigned.\n");
            }
        }

    }

    //replace an empty seat with a person in the seating chart
    public static void seatingChart(boolean seat[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {  
            if(seat[i]) {
                System.out.print(name + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("o ");
            }    

            if(i % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

All of the code for reference:

```
package programs;

import java.util.*;

public class SeatingChart {

    java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    boolean seating[] = new boolean[24];

    boolean runAgain = true;
    int input;
    static String name;

    //runs the program with four options
    public void runProgram()
    {
        do{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart,"
                    + " 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            switch(input)
            {
            case 1:
                emptySeat();
                break;
            case 2:
                seatingChart(seating);
                break;
            case 3:
                clearSeats(seating);
                break;
            case 4:
                runAgain = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("That is not an option, please try again!");
            }
        }while(runAgain);
    }

    //changes an empty seat to a student's name at any location
    public void emptySeat()
    {
        System.out.println("Who will be taking this seat?");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Which seat would you like (1-24)\n");
        int seat = scan.nextInt();
        if (seat > 0 && seat <= 24) {
            if (seating[seat - 1]) {
                System.out.print("That seat is taken.\n");
            } else {
                seating[seat - 1] = true;
                System.out.print("Seat number " + seat + " was assigned.\n");
            }
        }

    }

    //replace an empty seat with a person in the seating chart
    public static void seatingChart(boolean seat[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {  
            if(seat[i]) {
                System.out.print(name + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("o ");
            }    

            if(i % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    //clears all the seats
    public void clearSeats(boolean seat[])
    {
            for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {  
                if(seat[i]) {
                    System.out.print("empty seat  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("empty seat  ");
                }    

                if(i % 8 == 0) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SeatingChart prog = new SeatingChart();
        prog.runProgram();
    }

}
```

I am a beginner to java and help would be appreciated, thanks.

---

Edit:
Ok to make this more clear:
Current wrong output:

```
Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
1
Who will be taking this seat?
Bob
Which seat would you like (1-24)
3
Seat number 3 was assigned.

Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
2
o 
o Bob o o o o o o 
o o o o o o o o 
o o o o o o o 
Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
1
Who will be taking this seat?
Joe
Which seat would you like (1-24)
5
Seat number 5 was assigned.

Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
2
o 
o Joe o Joe o o o o 
o o o o o o o o 
o o o o o o o
```

What I want the output to be:

```
Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
1
Who will be taking this seat?
Bob
Which seat would you like (1-24)
3
Seat number 3 was assigned.

Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
2

o o Bob o o o o o
o o o o o o o o 
o o o o o o o o
Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
1
Who will be taking this seat?
Joe
Which seat would you like (1-24)
5
Seat number 5 was assigned.

Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart, 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program
2
o o Bob o Joe o o o
o o o o o o o o 
o o o o o o o o
```

Comment: You know how to make an array of booleans. Should be fairly easy to figure out how to make an array of strings...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here you go, ask me if you don't understand anything, and also pinch green thingy if this helps you :)

Notice that you don't need static variable name, and also check the method clearSeats im not sure if thats what you ment to do with it, anyways hope this helps you

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProblemSolved {

    java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    boolean seating[] = new boolean[24];
    String seatings[] = new String[24];

    boolean runAgain = true;
    int input;


    //runs the program with four options
    public void runProgram()
    {
        do{
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Press 1 to change a seat, 2 to print the seating chart,"
                    + " 3 to clear all the seats or 4 to exit the program");
            input = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            switch(input)
            {
            case 1:
                emptySeat();
                break;
            case 2:
                seatingChart(seatings);
                break;
            case 3:
                clearSeats(seatings);
                break;
            case 4:
                runAgain = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("That is not an option, please try again!");
            }
        }while(runAgain);
    }

    //changes an empty seat to a student's name at any location
    public void emptySeat()
    {
        System.out.println("Who will be taking this seat?");

        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Which seat would you like (1-24)\n");
        int seat = scan.nextInt();
        if (seat > 0 && seat <= 24) {
            if (seatings[seat-1] != null) {
                System.out.print("That seat is taken.\n");
            } else {
                seatings[seat - 1] = name;
                System.out.print("Seat number " + seat + " was assigned.\n");
            }
        }

    }

    //replace an empty seat with a person in the seating chart
    public static void seatingChart(String seat[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {  
            if(seat[i]!=null) {
                System.out.print(seat[i] + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("o ");
            }    

            if((i+1) % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    //clears all the seats
    public void clearSeats(String seat[])
    {
            for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {  
                if(seat[i] == null) {
                    System.out.print("empty seat  ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("not empty seat  ");
                }    

                if((i+1) % 8 == 0) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ProblemSolved prog = new ProblemSolved();
        prog.runProgram();
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. And after looking through your changes, I understand it.

Comment: No problem mate, here to help you

Comment: Thanks for the empty seat method as well, that is what I was basically planning to do

Comment: Also an issue I have is that the first seat is on a different line. I know it has something to do with this:
```
    //replace an empty seat with a person in the seating chart
    public static void seatingChart(String seat[]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {  
            if(seat[i]!=null) {
                System.out.print(seat[i] + " ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("o ");
            }    

            if(i % 8 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```
specifically the %8. Any idea why?

Comment: Ill check it out when I get home brother

Comment: Hey man, it is because 0/8 also gives you 0 as residue from a division so he will do the println, gotta do something with that mate

Comment: Like validate that i isn't 0 also!

Comment: Above validation won't work, what works is the validation I put on the edit of the answer, just do if((i+1)%8 == 0)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to change `boolean seating[]` to `String seating[]`. Every time you save a new seat, instead of saving it as a boolean, save person's name into that item in array:

```
String seating[] = new String[24];
// ...
if (seat > 0 && seat <= 24) {
        if (seating[seat - 1] != null) {
            System.out.print("That seat is taken.\n");
        } else {
            seating[seat - 1] = name;
            System.out.print("Seat number " + seat + " was assigned.\n");
        }
    }
```

And then

```
public static void seatingChart(String seat[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < seat.length; i++) {  
        if(seat[i] != null) {
            System.out.print(seat[i] + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print("o ");
        }    

        if(i % 8 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```